# How to change Tcl error prefix?

Tags: exception, error-handling, tcl

The Tcl [`error`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/error.htm) command writes the specified message to `stderr` adding to it a prefix "Error: ".

Is it possible to change that prefix with something else like "ERROR: " or "MyError: " ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `error` command itself does not write anything to anywhere other than the Tcl result. What it *actually* does is throw an exception (of type “error”; TCL_ERROR at the C API level). The code that prefixes it with “`Error:` ” is just the standard fallback handler, but you can use your own by having your main script use [`catch`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/catch.htm) to trap any result and decide what to do with it (or `try …` from 8.6 onwards, which is easier to use when trapping specific problems).

```
if {[catch {source realscript.tcl} msg]} {
    # Caught an error!
    puts stderr "Oh noes! Teh errorz iz atakkin! $msg"
    puts stderr $::errorInfo
    exit 1
}
```

---

OK, if you're using 8.5 then a slightly better way to write that is:

```
if {[catch {source realscript.tcl} msg resultdict]} {
    # Caught an error!
    puts stderr "Oh noes! Teh errorz iz atakkin! $msg"
    puts stderr [dict get $resultdict -errorinfo]
    exit 1
}
```

There's lots of other interesting stuff in the result dictionary, which you might or might not be interested in. Have a poke around.